# How to set connections and variables in airflow using docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I'm creating a dev environment to use airflow for testing. I'm using the `docker-compose.yaml` file available on Airflow website. I would like to know if it is possible to set my connections and variables in this file. I know that I can establish a connection using `AIRFLOW_CONN_...` with URI parameters. Is it possible use `AIRFLOW_CONN_...` and `EXPORT VARIABLE` inside the `docker-compose.yaml` file?

My `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.1.4
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# AIRFLOW_GID                  - Group ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 0
#
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: "3"
x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.4}
  # build: .
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- pymssql pymongo unidecode apache-airflow-providers-mongo apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-0}"
  depends_on: &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"',
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.1.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID and AIRFLOW_GID environment variables, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:${AIRFLOW_GID}" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:${AIRFLOW_GID:-0}"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Should `AIRFLOW_CONN_...` be added in `environment` settings, something like:

```
environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CONN__TEST: "uri/here"
    export AIRFLOW_VAR_FOO=JSON
```

Comment: Please include code! There is not enough information here for someone to help you. What have you tried? Include errors experienced! We cannot help without a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think this was not necessary in this case, since docker-compose.yaml file is available on Airflow website. But no problem, I'll edit the original post with the code and what I'm trying to do. If you could remove the downvote I ll be greatful.

Comment: Please refer to "How do I ask a good question?" for why it is necessary (and likely why someone downvoted): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No problem, I've updated the question. My bad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only adding `AIRFLOW_CONN_YOURCONNECTION` or `AIRFLOW_VAR_YOURVARIABLE` is enough. Note that environment variables for connections and variables use *single* underscores, not double. You don't have to export environment variables in your docker-compose file, they are set upon starting containers.

For more information about environment variables and Docker Compose, see the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers

Comment: The [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#storing-a-connection-in-environment-variables) states: "Connections created this way will not show up in the Airflow UI or using `airflow connections list`. You can use `airflow connections get {CONN_ID}` if you already know the `CONN_ID`."

Answer (score 6):

The `environment` variables ARE used in the `docker-compose.yaml` and ARE used when the process starts. If you want to use them without modifying the `docker-compose.yaml`, then:

1. Instead of `environment` use `env_file`, as:

```
env_file:
  - ./development.env
  - ./other-environment.env
```

3. You include your variables in your `development.env` as (all these environment variables are being used per [airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html)):

```
AIRFLOW_CORE_EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
AIRFLOW_CORE_SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
AIRFLOW_CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
AIRFLOW_CELERY_BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
AIRFLOW_CORE_FERNET_KEY: ""
AIRFLOW_CORE_DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
AIRFLOW_CORE_LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
AIRFLOW_API_AUTH_BACKEND: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- pymssql pymongo unidecode apache-airflow-providers-mongo apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark}
```

4. You add your `*.env` file to your `.gitignore` so that is local (not added to git). Whatever you need added to your `.git`, then do not add it.
5. You can test by running (this will show you all the variables replaced):

```
docker-compose config
```

6. Troubleshoot by starting your composition, check your containers using `docker ps -a` and try to enter any of the container with `docker run -it <sha> sh` and check if anything was not initialized as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Variables and connections can also be set using `JSON`, `YAML` and `.env` files, with the [Local Filesystem Secrets Backend](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/local-filesystem-secrets-backend.html). Just need to set the environment variable `AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND` to `airflow.secrets.local_filesystem.LocalFilesystemBackend` and `AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS` to the paths at which the files will be present inside the container. Sample files below:

**variables.yml:**

```yaml
env_name: local
props: |-
  {
    "key_one": "value_one",
    "key_two": "value_two"
  }
```

**connections.yml:**

```yaml
postgres_test:
  conn_type: postgres
  host: localhost
  schema: postgres
  login: testuser
  password: testpwd
  port: 5432
```

**docker-compose.yml:**(Uses `SequentialExecutor`. Should be the same with `CeleryExecutor` as well)

```yaml
services:
  airflow:
    image: apache/airflow:slim-2.7.2-python3.11
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: SequentialExecutor
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER: /data/dags
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: airflow
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: airflow
      AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: 'true'
      AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND: airflow.secrets.local_filesystem.LocalFilesystemBackend
      AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS: '{"variables_file_path": "/data/variables.yml", "connections_file_path": "/data/connections.yml"}'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8793:8793'
      - '8794:8794'
    volumes:
      - ./airflow:/data
    command: 'standalone'
```